# Swagger for Minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, minimal-apis

I'm trying to use minimal API in my project. the problem I'm facing is that the traditional Controllers are in a way that swagger generates a seperate section for each and every Controller. but I can't see an option to add this kind of seperation in Minimal API.
is it possible to add different sections in Swagger using minimal API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`WithTags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/openapi?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-tags-to-the-openapi-description) extension method:

> OpenAPI supports using tag objects to categorize [operations](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/). These tags are typically used to group operations in the Swagger UI. These tags can be added to an operation by invoking the `WithTags` extension method on the endpoint with the desired tags.

```cs
app.MapGet("/one", () => "Hello World!").WithTags("xyz");
app.MapGet("/two", () => "Hello World!").WithTags("xyz");
```

[image]

It pairs very nicely with [`MapGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/route-handlers?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-groups):

> The `MapGroup` extension method helps organize groups of endpoints with a common prefix. It reduces repetitive code and allows for customizing entire groups of endpoints with a single call to methods like `RequireAuthorization` and `WithMetadata` which add endpoint metadata.

```cs
var adminGroup = app.MapGroup("/admin")
    .WithTags("admin");
adminGroup.MapGet("/adminThing", () => "some");
adminGroup.MapPost("/doAdminThing", () => "some1");

var userGroup = app.MapGroup("/user")
    .WithTags("user");
userGroup.MapGet("/userThing", () => "some");
userGroup.MapPost("/doUserThing", () => "some1");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.WithOpenApi()` extension, e.g

```cs
app.MapGet("/", ...)
 .WithOpenApi(o => {Tags = new List<string>{"Section1"}})
```